# Remove commas from numbers in a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, digit-separator

I have folder info for all user folders. It is dumped out to a CSV file as follows:

```
Servername, F:\Users\user, 9,355.7602 MB, 264, 3054, 03/15/2000 13:28:48, 12/10/2018 11:58:29
```

We are unable to work with the data as is due to the thousands separator in the 3rd column. I could run the report scripts again, but we have a lot of file servers and a large number of users on one in particular, so running it again is very time consuming. The reason the commas are there is that the data was written as a string not a number.

I can import and convert, the only problem is that any number over 1000 will be wrong and then all other data is 1 column off. I would like to replace any comma between 2 numbers. It doesn't seem it would be that hard to do with PowerShell, but I am not having any luck finding anything.

Comment: what about the 4th, 5th, 6th, and 7th column being also numbers and this columns are being separated by a comma? Probably any script or logic will remove this. I would suggest you run the report script again.

Comment: CSV is one of the worst data interchange formats ever. Never use CSV. Use a useful seperator like pipe `|` or tab instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that columns of data are ***comma plus space*** separated and ***your numbers have no spaces***, you can use the `-replace` operator for this.

```
$line = 'Servername, F:\Users\user, 9,355.7602 MB, 264, 3054, 03/15/2000 13:28:48, 12/10/2018 11:58:29'
$line -replace '(?<=\d),(?=\d)'
```

If you are reading the data from a file, you can read the data with [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6), replace your data, and update the file with [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6).

```
(Get-Content file.csv) -replace '(?<=\d),(?=\d)' | Set-Content file.csv
```

If the file is large, you can utilize the faster [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6) statement.

```
$data = switch -regex -file file.csv {
          '(?<=\d),(?=\d)' { $_ -replace '(?<=\d),(?=\d)' }
          default {$_}
        }
$data | Set-Content file.csv
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\d)` uses a positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=)` that matches a single digit `\d`.
- `(?=\d)` uses a positive lookahead assertion `(?=)` that matches a single digit. You could replace this with `(?=\d{3})` to match 3 consecutive digits after the comma.
- Since you want to replace the target comma with empty string, you do not need a replacement string.

---

Typically, it would be best to stick with commands that work with CSV data or files. However, ***if your data contains commas and you aren't qualifying*** your text, it may be difficult to distinguish between data and delimiters. If you have a clear way of making that distinction, you are better off using [ConvertFrom-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-6) for already read data or [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) for files. You will need to define headers either in the files or in the command.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I figured it wasn't hard, just don't know a lot about the replace function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

It was my oversight that the `,` in the dataset is not delimited, which causes this answer to not work as expected as the comma is seen as a column separator when parsing the CSV. I'm going to leave it as it does explain how to generally manipulate the data as you'd expect, if the column data were escaped property. However, [@AdminOfThings' answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58923471/584676) should work for your specific case here, and will fix the erroneous defined column without relying on parsing the CSV content as a CSV first.

---

Import the data using `Import-Csv`, then remove any `,` in the third column. This assumes that you have no values where `,` is the decimal separator:

If you have headers in the CSV, you won't need to define header names or get fancy with writing the CSV back out:

```
Import-Csv -Path \path\to\file.csv | Foreach-Object {
  $_.ColumnName = $_.ColumnName -replace ','
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path \path\to\file.csv
```

The way this works is that we import the CSV as an operable `PSCustomObject`, then for each line we take whatever the column name with the size is and remove the `,` from it. Finally, we export the modified `PSCustomObject` back out to the original CSV.

If you don't have headers, it gets a little trickier since we have to define temporary headers, but `Export-Csv` doesn't have an option to skip writing out headers:

```
Import-Csv -Path \path\to\file.csv -Headers Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 |
  Foreach-Object {
    $_.Col3 = $_.Col3 -replace ','
  } | ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  Set-Content -Path \path\to\file.csv
```

This does the same thing as the first block of code, but since we don't want to export the temporary headers, we have to get creative. First, note we reference the target column with the temporary header name. Instead of piping the modified CSV object right to `Export-Csv`, first we want to convert the object to CSV using `ConvertTo-Csv`. We then use `Select-Object` to skip the first line of the converted CSV text, which is the header, so we just have the row data and column values. Finally, we use `Set-Content` to write the CSV text without the header back to the original file.

Comment: I'm not understanding how this distinguishes between `,` as a column delimiter and `,` and a number group separator.  I thought you were going to suggest re-assembling the size split across two columns, but instead it seems you're expecting it to be left intact.  How can you remove the comma from the size column when the comma itself causes it to be parsed into two columns?  `'Servername, F:\Users\user, 9,355.7602 MB, 264, 3054, 03/15/2000 13:28:48, 12/10/2018 11:58:29' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8` yields `Col3 : 9` and `Col4 : 355.7602 MB`.

Comment: Actually, that's a good call out, it was an oversight on my part. But, the real issue is that you received a CSV with this bad data in it, an unescaped delimiter. Whatever process generated it needs to be fixed because as is it's unparseable as expected. I'm going to leave this answer because it does outline how you would properly work with the data if the `,` was escaped as it should have been, but @AdminOfThings answer will probably be your best bet to fix the data that was already delivered in one swoop.

Comment: Well, yes, ideally the CSV would not have been written with this numeric formatting and the question would not need to exist.  But then that's the entire point of the question: given that the CSV _was_ produced this way, how can they make use of the file they already have instead of having to re-run the report?  If the CSV had been written properly your answer could be simplified to `Import-Csv -Path \path\to\file.csv | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path \path\to\file.csv` or, better yet, `# Do nothing`.  (I'm not the author of the question, by the way.)

Comment: My bad, thought you were OP. But your statement isn't true, the column data could have been enclosed in quotes which would have property escaped the `,`, which is how I initially read the data sample. The question was "[how to] remove commas from numbers in a CSV" and given a valid CSV file this method would work fine.

Comment: "the column data could have been enclosed in quotes" - But it **wasn't** enclosed in quotes.  "given a valid CSV file" - But you're **not** given a valid CSV.  Again, this is the whole point of the question.  Answering based on what the data _should_ have been is not helpful because if the data were properly formatted in the first place this question wouldn't exist.  A useful answer would address what the data actually _is_, which is in an invalid format and the question is how to fix it without the use of a time machine.